# Send a private message from a user account to another user inbox with Rest FB

Tags: java, facebook, restfb, private-messaging

Is there anyway to send a private message from my account into another user inbox using Rest FB?

The thing is, at first, I'm receiving messages to my inbox from different users( not all are my friends), and I'm taking these messages & saving them into a database, along with every sender id.

Then, I want to send a specific link to each correspondent user in a private message.

Is it possible using Rest FB ?

Answer (score 0):

There's no such implementation. So no it's not possible.